# Convert ctypes byte array to Python list of floating point numbers

Tags: python, c, arrays, casting, ctypes

I have allocated an array and cast it using the Python ctypes module:

```
    dataC = ctypes.cast(crt.malloc(size), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
```

in order to get byte data from a C library:

```
    someClib.getData(handle, dataC)
```

Now this array is actually an array of C float types.  How can I convert it to a Python list of floating type numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast to a pointer to float:

```
floatPtr = ctypes.cast(dataC, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
```

And then use a list comprehension, for example, to pull out the floats:

```
floatList = [floatPtr[i] for i in range(arrayLength)]
```

Now, only you know the value of `arrayLength` but it seems plausible to me that it is equal to `size / ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)`.

Comment: Backing up a step, allocate the float array to begin with, i.e. `dataC = (ctypes.c_float * arrayLength)()`. It's sized, so there's no need for a list comprehension. At least use `dataC = (ctypes.c_ubyte * size)()`. Using the C runtime's `malloc` is usually the wrong approach.

Comment: @eryksun That sounds sensible. I was answering naively the question as asked.

Comment: @eryksun I'll try your approach - it would simplify the code.